# How can I get the json format of my google sheet in google app script?

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to get the json format of my google sheets. I tried many tutorials but it ain't working.

Comment: What do you mean by  "the json format of my google sheet"? Also please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
function shjsn() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('SheetName');
  const vs=sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  return JSON.stringify(vs);
}
```

or Perhaps for the entire spreadsheet:

```
function ssjsn() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const shts=ss.getSheets();
  let vs=[];
  shts.forEach(function(sh,i){vs.push(sh.getDataRange().getValues());});
  return JSON.stringify(vs);
}
```